# problema de galeria de imagenes con javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

resulta que tengo una duda hice la siguiente galería y pues me parece que esta correcto el botón de la derecha pero al oprimir el botón de la izquierda se reinicia a posición cero... un ejemplo es si estuviera en la posición 2 del vector, oprimo el botón de la izquierda y deseo volver a la posición 1 del vector  pero se reinicia a 0 y lo oprimo otra vez aparece la posición 1 del vector y ya después si retoma la función de ir desde la posición que este hacia atrás, como podría corregir este error ya que e intentado de varias maneras y siempre sucede lo mismo:

**HTML**

```
<div id="imgCambio">
    <center>
       <button id = "izq"    onclick = "cambiarI()">&lArr;</button>
       <img    id = "mostrarImg" src = "interface/imagenes/1.jpg">
       <button id = "der"   onclick = "cambiarD()">&rArr;</button>
   </center>
 </div>
```

**javaScript**

```
var miImg=document.getElementById('mostrarImg');

var imagen = 

['./interface/imagenes/1.jpg','./interface/imagenes/2.jpg',
'./interface/imagenes/3.jpg'];

var imgPosi=1;

function cambiarD()
{
    miImg.setAttribute("src",imagen[imgPosi]);
    imgPosi++;
    if (imgPosi>2) 
    {
        imgPosi=0;
    }
}


function cambiarI()
{

    miImg.setAttribute("src",imagen[imgPosi]);imgPosi--;
    if (imgPosi<0 ) 
    {
        imgPosi=2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Agrega tu HTML como texto, no como foto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu problemas es que cambias el attributo `src` a una posicion sin antes validar que sea valida o exista en arreglo fuera de que estas limitando tu codigo a solo 3 imagenes!
**puedes hacerlo asi:**

```js
var miImg=document.getElementById('mostrarImg');

var imagen =['https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/A-gray-cat-crying-looking-upset.jpg','https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*mONNI1lG9VuiqovpnYqicA.jpeg',
'https://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/549585-istock-909106260.jpg?itok=ds7LqH1N&resize=1100x1100','https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg'];


// una funcion random para obtener una imagen diferente al iniciar o la que decidas
var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagen.length);
miImg.setAttribute("src",imagen[rn]);

// variable contador la inicializamos con el valor del random puede ser 0 si lo deseas 
//  en este caso lo e hecho asi como un ejemplo
var imgPosi=rn;

// funcion cambio derecha
function cambiarD(){
    //aumentamos el contador
    imgPosi++;

    // validamos antes de hacer cualquier cambio
    // que el contador no sea mayor a la cantidad e posiciones en nuestro arreglo lenth es la longitud del mismo
    // lo utilizo porque asi podras tener la cantidad de imagenes en el arreglo que deses
    if (imgPosi > imagen.length-1) {
        // reiniciamos las posiciones a 0
        imgPosi=0;
    }
    // cambiamos el src de la imagen
    miImg.setAttribute("src",imagen[imgPosi]);
}

// funccion cambiar isquierda
function cambiarI(){
    // reducimos el contador -1
    imgPosi--;

    //validamos que no este por debajo de 0 que es la posicion inicial de nuestro arreglo 
    if (imgPosi < 0){
        // si esta por debajo de 0 hacemos que contador aumente hasta la longitud del arreglo
        imgPosi=imagen.length-1;
    }
    // cambiamos el src de la imagen
    miImg.setAttribute("src",imagen[imgPosi]);
}
```

```html
   <div id="imgCambio">

     <center>

       <button id = "izq"    onclick = "cambiarI()">&lArr;</button>

       <img    id = "mostrarImg" src = "https://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/549585-istock-909106260.jpg?itok=ds7LqH1N&resize=1100x1100" width="250px">

       <button id = "der"   onclick = "cambiarD()">&rArr;</button>

    </center>

  </div>
```

**version optimizada!**
con el codigo anterior tenemos un inconveniente en cuanto a rendimiento, si las imagenes son muy grandes, son demaciadas o el usuario pose una conexion lenta
 esto es porque al darle `setAttribute` la web debe solicitar nuevamente la imagen a dicha url para mostrarla.
podemos corregirlo creando objetos y cargando solo 1 vez dicha imagen desde su url!
**ejemplo:**

```js
var miImg=document.getElementById('mostrarImg');


var imagen =['https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/A-gray-cat-crying-looking-upset.jpg','https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*mONNI1lG9VuiqovpnYqicA.jpeg',
'https://images.mentalfloss.com/sites/default/files/styles/mf_image_16x9/public/549585-istock-909106260.jpg?itok=ds7LqH1N&resize=1100x1100','https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg'];

// creamos un loop para recorrer el arreglo
for (let i = imagen.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    // creamos un elemento imagen
    let img = new Image();
    // le asiganmos un width por defecto puede omitirse
    img.width = 250;
    // le asignamos el src
    img.src = imagen[i];
    // remplazamos la posicion del arreglo con el nuevo objeto
    imagen[i] = img;
}

// una funcion random para obtener una imagen diferente al iniciar o la que decidas
var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagen.length);
miImg.appendChild(imagen[rn]);

// variable contador
var imgPosi=rn;

// funcion cambio derecha
function cambiarD(){
    //aumentamos el contador
    imgPosi++;

    // validamos antes de hacer cualquier cambio
    // que el contador no sea mayor a la cantidad e posiciones en nuestro arreglo lenth es la longitud del mismo
    // lo utilizo porque asi podras tener la cantidad de imagenes en el arreglo que deses
    if (imgPosi > imagen.length-1) {
        // reiniciamos las posiciones a 0
        imgPosi=0;
    }
    // eliminamos todo el contendido dentro del elemento
    miImg.innerHTML = ''; 
    // agregamos el nuevo elemento imagen
    miImg.appendChild(imagen[imgPosi]);
}

// funccion cambiar isquierda
function cambiarI(){
    // reducimos el contador -1
    imgPosi--;

    //validamos que no este por debajo de 0 que es la posicion inicial de nuestro arreglo 
    if (imgPosi < 0){
        // si esta por debajo de 0 hacemos que contador aumente hasta la longitud del arreglo
        imgPosi=imagen.length-1;
    }
    // eliminamos todo el contendido dentro del elemento
    miImg.innerHTML = '';
    // agregamos un nuevo elemengo imagen
    miImg.appendChild(imagen[imgPosi]);
}
```

```html
   <div id="imgCambio">

     <center>

       <button id = "izq"    onclick = "cambiarI()">&lArr;</button>

      <!--  cambiamos la imagen por un span contenedor -->
       <span id = "mostrarImg"></span>
       <button id = "der"   onclick = "cambiarD()">&rArr;</button>

    </center>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas sumando o restando valores al contador despues de haberlo asginando y deberias hacerlo antes.

```
var miImg=document.getElementById('mostrarImg');

var imagen = 

['./interface/imagenes/1.jpg','./interface/imagenes/2.jpg',
'./interface/imagenes/3.jpg'];

var imgPosi=1;

function cambiarD()
{

    imgPosi++;
    if (imgPosi>2) 
    {
        imgPosi=0;
    }
    miImg.setAttribute("src",imagen[imgPosi]);
}


function cambiarI()
{

    imgPosi--;
    if (imgPosi<0 ) 
    {
        imgPosi=2;
    }
    miImg.setAttribute("src",imagen[imgPosi]);

}
```

Comment: En el código de ejemplo que te he puesto puedes ver que se suma +1 al valor de imgPosi y luego se hace el cambio de la imagen en cambio en tu código primero se hace el cambio de imagen y luego le cambias el valor al contador imgPosi

Comment: gracias ya entendí que era lo que provocaba ese error gracias a tu ejemplo